# Radar Plots within ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, radar-chart

I understand this question has been asked before, but in using some of the past answers I still cannot produce the radar chart I would like. I have used this, [as an example of a radar chart I am trying to reproduce.](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/72298_c1ba7f77276a4f27a0f375cadc9fac5d.html) But I can't seem to figure out the last bits.

This is what I have so far:[image]

I am a unhappy with the following:
1. The polar grid on the background. How do I create one such that it does go through the middle of every bar? It looks like it does at first, but then stops and I cannot figure out why. If I cannot make it go through the middle, then I would like it to go on the outside of each bar. If that doesn't work, then maybe just slice the radar chart into 8 equal sections?
2. Why is there a width between some bars, but others not so much.

Code:

```
t<-12
angle_bucket<-seq(0,2*pi-2*pi/t,2*pi/t) 
angle_group<-seq(1,length(angle_bucket),1)                   
meanL<-c(17.289,20.7857,18.675,10.4,0,0,22.1,19.5,18.02,19.5,30.35,29.83)
normized<-c(1,0.368,0.2105,0.05263,0,0,0.10526,0.21056,0.5263,0.157894,0.7368,0.8421)
ang_dfp<-data.frame(angle_bucket,angle_group,meanL,normized) 
ang_dfp$angle_group<-as.factor(ang_dfp$angle_group)
ang_dfp$angle_bucket<-ang_dfp$angle_bucket+2*pi/t/2    
p<-ggplot()+
  geom_bar(data=ang_dfp,aes(x=angle_bucket,y=normized, fill=meanL), stat = "identity")+
  scale_fill_viridis_c(alpha=1,begin=0,end=1,direction=-1,option='plasma',aesthetics ='fill')+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:nlevels(ang_dfp$angle_group))+
  #Theme
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.text=element_blank(),
    axis.line=element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1), "cm"),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA),
    legend.position = 'none'
  )+
  coord_polar(theta='x',start=0,direction=-1)
p
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely the example you link to, they create the plot using a factor. You are using a numeric (continuous) variable. I coerce `angle_bucket` to factor.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data=ang_dfp,aes(x=as.factor(angle_bucket),y=normized, fill=meanL), stat = "identity")+
  scale_fill_viridis_c(alpha=1,begin=0,end=1,direction=-1,option='plasma',aesthetics ='fill')+
  # scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:nlevels(ang_dfp$angle_group))+
  #Theme
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.text=element_blank(),
    axis.line=element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1), "cm"),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA),
    legend.position = 'none') +
  coord_polar(theta='x',start=0,direction=-1)
```

[image]

Comment: I know I did not ask this orginally. Is there a way to remove the extra spacing? As in remove the last section of the circle above the highest bar.

Comment: @JackArmstrong settings scale limits didn't work. I'd have to research this a bit more but I'm pressed for time right now. My suggestion would be to post this as a new question.

Comment: You have to draw in the polar grid yourself with horizontal and vertical lines. I will post when I have a chance as part of the original question.